# I need to set-up the blocked machine to relay to the unblocked machine using a different port

Tags: smtp

I have two Windows Server 2003 machines sitting in a network. Server B has port 25 open and can relay emails to the local network's smtp server. Server A does not have port 25 open. How can I set it up to send emails through another port to the SMTP server? I am thinking if I can setup a local SMTP communication between my servers on a different port and let Server B send Server A's emails. Is that possible?